# Open HTML source code from dynamic link from flex mobile application

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

It's not like I have not tried and I want ready made solution. So don't came this thought in between.

I want to access some of field like title and h1 (header) from html page link and display it in my flex application as label text. For this I need to open Source code of HTML page link in my flex application to retrieve data from there.

Any help/suggestion are most welcome!

cheers

Comment: Are the HTML page and the Flex SWF hosted on the same web server?

Comment: I am creating one application. I have HTML page link/url and I want to display only title and header information instead of whole page. Too confuse to implement!

Answer (score 0):

Using [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html) in a Flex Application can retrieve the contents of a remote URL. A [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) can do the same.  It is not usually used for retrieving HTML pages; but they can be.  You'll need a crossdomain.xml file in place on the remote server you want to access or else these requests will fail for security reasons.

Once you get the page source, you'll have to process it.  I don't think you can assume that an HTML Document is valid XML, you'll have to use string processing instread of e4x to get at the contents of the Title and/or H1 tags.

Comment: I am creating one application. I have HTML page link/url and I want to display only title and header information instead of whole page. Too confuse to implement!